# Django configuration to send email

Tags: django

Some facts:
I am working on localhost with devserver. I have a Django project where the email sending works perfectly. I set up a new Django project, both 1.4.5, I copy / paste the email settings form the working project (EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_PORT...) in settings.py to the new one, I open a shell with manage.py and load send_mail from django.core.mail on the first project it can send emails (I receive them in my email client), on the second the email never gets sent. I tried with various servers, gmail and gandi. I tried directly with the smtplib in pure Python code and it works with the same settings. While sending the mail with the first project and with smtplib I can see the function takes a few seconds to return the prompt in the command line but with the second project it returns the prompt immediately which makes me think nothing is happening.

So my question is what could be wrong in my new project's config? Where to look? And if possible how to debug that? (the send_mail function only returns 1, which is the number of mails I have sent, is there a way to get a trace back or some useful error message?)

Comment: just one question, are you using DEBUG=true in your settings?

Comment: @lalo in both projects I have DEBUG=True on my localhost and DEBUG=False on a server (the behaviour is the same on the server, email does not work for the new project).

Answer (score 0):

to answer one of your questions:

*>>> how to debug that?*

Use [`pdb.set_trace()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#pdb.set_trace) just before the call to whatever you want to debug.

Comment: could you expand on how to use pdb with the send_mail function please?

Comment: in my experience I use pdb to stop the execution of code and start debugging. In my question there is no code execution, just a function that does not return a message that could be helpful to me. I don't see how pdb would help me here the way I use it. If you know a way to use it differently that could be relevant here please share.

Comment: Hi Bastian, nothing stops you from using `pdb` to step *into* the "send mail" function (it doesn't matter if it's a django library). You can use `step` on the pdb prompt for that.

Answer (score 0):

I knew it was easy, it had to be a setting and indeed it was. I don't where that one comes from, may be it appears by default in new django projects, I have no idea but I had

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"
```

in my settings file, far from my email settings and I had never entered it myself. Changing it to SMTP or commenting it makes Django actually send the email.